# How to change image source when a property changes through databinding in XAML from viewmodel in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvm, data-binding

I am working on providing wishlist feature for my app by tapping wishlist icon on each product in list through MVVM. Once tapped, an API call is made to update database(add/remove from wishlist table). Based on result from api call, I updated the specific product's respective property to either 'True' or 'False'. Once property updated, I want to change the icon image source of corresponding product. I am using trigger on wishlist icon to differentiate non-wishlist and wiahlist products while binding the list itself.

My code is below,

**MODEL**

```
public class PublisherProducts
{
   public long ProductId { get; set; }
   public string ProductName { get; set; }
   public string ImageURL { get; set; }
   public decimal Price { get; set; }
   public bool IsWishlistProduct { get; set; }
}
```

**VIEWMODEL**

```
public class OnlineStoreViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
 private ObservableCollection<PublisherProducts> publisherProducts;
 public Command<long> WishlistTapCommand { get; }

 public OnlineStoreViewModel()
 {
    publisherProducts = new ObservableCollection<PublisherProducts>();
    WishlistTapCommand = new Command<long>(OnWishlistSelected);
 }

 public ObservableCollection<PublisherProducts> PublisherProducts
 {
   get { return publisherProducts; }
   set
   {
    publisherProducts = value;
    OnPropertyChanged();
   }
 }                  

 public async Task GetProducts(long selectedCategoryId)
 {
  try
    {
      ...
      PublisherProducts = new ObservableCollection<PublisherProducts>(apiresponse.ProductList);
      ...
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {  ... }
    finally {  ... }
 }

 async void OnWishlistSelected(long tappedProductId)
 {
   if (tappedProductId <= 0)
     return;
   else
     await UpdateWishlist(tappedProductId);
 }

 public async Task UpdateWishlist(long productId)
 {
   try
   {
    var wishlistResponse = // api call
    var item = PublisherProducts.Where(p => p.ProductId == productId).FirstOrDefault();
    item.IsWishlistProduct = !item.IsWishlistProduct;

    PublisherProducts = publisherProducts;  *Stuck here to toggle wishlist icon*

    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("", wishlistResponse.Message, "Ok");
   }
   catch (Exception ex) {  ... }
   finally {  ... }
 }    
}
```

**XAML**

```
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" ... >
     <ContentPage.Content>
      <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout Padding="15,0,15,10">
         <FlexLayout x:Name="flxLayout" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding PublisherProducts}" ...>
           <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
               <AbsoluteLayout Margin="6" WidthRequest="150">
                  <Frame Padding="0" WidthRequest="150" CornerRadius="10" HasShadow="True">
                     <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                       <Image Source="{Binding ImageURL}" WidthRequest="130" HeightRequest="130" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                       <Label Text="{Binding ProductName}" Style="{StaticResource ProductNameStyle}"></Label>
                       ...
                       <StackLayout ...>
                         ...                                                
                         <Frame x:Name="wlistFrame" Padding="0" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" CornerRadius="10" BorderColor="#02457A">
                           <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                              <Image x:Name="wlImage" WidthRequest="13" HeightRequest="12" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="ic_wishlist_open">
                                <Image.Triggers>
                                   <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" Binding="{Binding IsWishlistProduct}" Value="true">
                                      <Setter Property="Source" Value="ic_wishlist_close" />
                                   </DataTrigger>
                                </Image.Triggers>
                               </Image>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:OnlineStoreViewModel}}, Path=WishlistTapCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ProductId}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />                                                        
                            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                         </Frame>

                       </StackLayout>                                            
                     </StackLayout>
                  </Frame>                                    
               </AbsoluteLayout>
             </DataTemplate>
          </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </FlexLayout>
       </StackLayout>          
     </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
  </ContentPage>
```

I am stuck at this place to change wishlist icon, when 'IsWishlistProduct' property value is changed in UpdateWishlist().

Comment: it would probably be simpler to display both icons and just toggle their IsVisible properties as needed

Comment: @Jason, You mean like IsVisible = {Binding IsWishlistProduct}. I tried that too. When value of 'IsWishlistProduct' changed in VM, it won't reflect in View.

Comment: your model has to implement INotifyPropertyChanged if you want the UI to refresh when the model changes

Comment: Model or ViewModel? VM already inherits that through BaseViewModel

Comment: whatever class contains `IsWishlistProduct` if that is the property that you want to trigger a UI change

Comment: Thanks. But if model do that, it breaks the MVVM concept, right? UI should get refresh by VM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226600/discussion-between-thamarai-t-and-jason).

Comment: @Jason, How to make VM to do refresh UI for this situation?

Comment: Your UI is already binding to properties of your model, adding INPC is not going to break anything

Comment: If you want to change source of image in runtime , you need to implement the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the model .

Comment: When I add INPC in respective model it works perfectly. Thanks Jason and Lucas Zhang for the support. Meanwhile, how can we achieve this with ViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

Guessing through your code, the BaseViewModel contains code similar to the following:

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   ...
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   ...

   public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
   {
      this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
   }
   ...
}
```

And your viewmodel should be like this:

```
...
public ObservableCollection<PublisherProducts> PublisherProducts
 {
   get { return publisherProducts; }
   set
   {
    publisherProducts = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PublisherProducts));
   }
 }
...
```

As Jason mentioned, If there is a change in data in the ViewModel, it is reflected in the UI when it is notified to the View through NotifyPropertyChanged. You already implemented "OnPropertyChanged" function in your BaseViewModel but it seems you don't pass the object name.

Comment: Yes, the BaseViewModel is similar. I tried as you said to pass object name. But it didn't reflect in UI.